# If PC with Great Weapon Master reduces a polymorphed creature to 0 hp, can they attack again?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, wild-shape, polymorph

The feat [Great Weapon Master](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/feats/great-weapon-master) (PHB, pg. 167) includes the following benefit:

> On your turn, when you score a critical hit with a melee weapon **or reduce a creature to 0 hit points with one, you can make one melee weapon attack as a bonus action.**

If a PC with this feat (let's say they're no higher than level 4 as so not to complicate this question with Extra Attack) attacks and successfully hits, say, a druid who has Wild Shaped into a [frog](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/frog) (1 hp), or they have been *polymorphed* into a frog. This attack will reduce the hp of the frog to 0. Let's assume the druid has enough hp to survive the remaining damage carried over to their normal form.

From [*polymorph*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/polymorph) (PHB, pg. 266):

> If it reverts as a result of dropping to 0 hit points, any excess damage carries over to its normal form. As long as the excess damage doesn't reduce the creature's normal form to 0 hit points, it isn't knocked unconscious.

From [Wild Shape](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/druid#WildShape) (PHB, pg. 67):

> However, if you revert as a result of dropping to 0 hit points, any excess damage carries over to your normal form.

Does the PC with the Great Weapon Master feat get to attack again as a bonus action as per the first quote? They reduced the frog's hp to 0, but not the druid's.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### Yes

You've provided all the relevant quotes that allow for it - there are two things that trigger on the same condition, the target reaching zero hit points, and there is no specification on which order they happen in. *Great Weapon Master* doesn't even require rendering the target unconscious, just bringing it to zero hit points.

In addition, *Great Weapon Master* feat does not specify who or what the bonus action attack has to be made against - character with Extra Attack would finish their normal routine (because they're in the middle of the Attack action) before moving on to the newly-available bonus action. If the feat said "a different creature", there might be some room for doubt, but it doesn't.